# Subsetting NetCDF file and returning tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf

I have a large (5GB) temperature netCDF file. The file is has 4 dimensions: time, pressure level, latitude, longitude.

The dataset has 31 timepoints and I am only interested in 5 pressure levels.

My parameter is temperature `t`:

```
from netCDF4._netCDF4 import Dataset
# Load the dataset
dataset = Dataset(path)
factor = dataset.variables['t']
```

To extract a 'cube' of temperature data from my `factor` variable around a centre cell, I would simply do subsetting, like this:

```
radius = 5 
# +1 because the subsetting does not include last index
lats_bounds = [nearest_latitude_index-radius,nearest_latitude_index+radius + 1] 
lons_bounds = [nearest_longitude_index-radius,nearest_longitude_index+radius +1]

#all timepoints
times_bounds = [0, len(times)] 

#just the last 5 pressure levels
pressure_level_bounds = [len(levels)-5, len(levels)] 

results = factor[times_bounds[0]:times_bounds[1],pressure_level_bounds[0]:pressure_level_bounds[1], lats_bounds[0]:lats_bounds[1],lons_bounds[0]:lons_bounds[1]]
```

The problem is that `results` will now of type `ndarray` with shape `(31,5,11,11)` and size `18755` (31*5*11*11) where every index holds just a single value.

I need the values from `results`, but for each value, I also need its corresponding timepoint, pressure level, latitude and longitude.

Ideally, I'd like to do subsetting as I have done, but my final result would be an array of tuples... Something like this:

```
# corresponding timestamp, pressure level, latitude, longitude
# and the temperature value extracted.
final = [
(2342342, 1000, 24.532, 53.531, 277),
(2342342, 1000, 74.453, 26.123, 351),
(2342342, 1000, 80.311, 56,345, 131),
...
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out xarray's [isel](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.isel_points.html#xarray.DataArray.isel). Translating the syntax from netCDF4 would look something like this:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(path)
factor = ds['t']

# note that levels/lon/lat are the names of dimensions in your Dataset
subset = factor.isel(levels=slice(-5, None),
                     lon=[1, 18, 48, 99], lat=[16, 28, 33, 35])
stacked = subset.stack(points=('time', 'levels', 'lon', 'lat'))

# This subset can be converted to a `pandas.Series`:
data = stacked.to_pandas()

# or it can be converted to a list of tuples
df = data.reset_index()
final = [tuple(row[1].values) for row in df.iterrows()]
```

Xarray also supports label based indexers (i.e. `lat=[29.3, 42.3]`) but for that, you should use the `sel` method instead of `isel`.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that you did not include `time` in your`factor.isel()`. Was that intentional? I need to use all timepoints, but in the future I may need just a subset. Timepoints are in unix timestamp format.

Comment: You can add `time=slice(start, end)` if you are going to slice along the time axis but for your current use case, this will give you all the timesteps.

Answer (score -2):

I'd use [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) for this task. But since you only have 35 times and 5 pressure levels,  I'd first simplify your approach and figure out how to do a single time and pressure level and a single lat,lon. Then figure out how to loop thru those indices to get your tuples. Something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(times)):
   for j in range(0, len(levels):
     print( results[i, j, nearest_lat_idx, nearest_lon_idx) )
```

Of course you could also add loops for the lat and lon as well but it's a bit ugly.